# Арина-Шерон / Арина — Шерон

Tags: пунктуация

Правда, что в соответствии с 8-м пунктом под цифрой е): http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxiv.html#sect93.8 — надо писать через тире, а не дефис?

> Все знают, что Георг — Леопольд и Арина — Шерон являются супердрузьями.

> Все знают, что Георг-Леопольд и Арина-Шерон являются супердрузьями.